# How to get cookies.txt for YouTube from Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, big-sur

I want to get my cookies.txt for YouTube so that I can youtube-dl my liked videos playlist.

How can I get my cookies from Safari? Opening the web inspector just lets me view them, I can't see how to download the text file from here.

Answer (score 2):

Safari cookies are located under `~/Library/Cookies`. However, they're binary cookies, so you'll have to decode it to human-readable (Netscape equivalent) cookies.

To do so, you would have to install [this tool](https://github.com/horrorho/burnt-cookie) and follow the instruction (I've never used it before, so I don't know if this still works.)

Personally, I'd rather just install Chrome (or a browser that uses Chromium, such as [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com), etc) and use extensions like [Get cookies.txt locally](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/get-cookiestxt-locally/cclelndahbckbenkjhflpdbgdldlbecc), though.

Comment: Is it just me, or is the folder empty now? (Safari, v16.0)

Comment: @AlexandreCassagne At least on my MBP (Monterey 12.4, Safari 16.0) I have cookies. I think it's just you.

Comment: It's empty for me as well on macOS 13.1 (Ventura) and Safari 16.2, and trying to run `sudo ls ~/Library/Cookies` gives "Operation not permitted"

Comment: I have cookies there (Safari 15.5; MacOS 10.15.7).

Comment: @LinusUnnebäck You can get around the "Operation not permitted" by by going into System Preferences > Security & Privacy and giving Full Disk Access to Terminal. However, on my machine, after doing this, I've discovered that the folder is empty