# How to download private YouTube videos with Safari as browser?

Tags: macos, safari, big-sur

How can I download my private youtube videos?

I use `youtube-dl` to download youtube videos normally. To download private videos apparently it needs a cookies.txt which I can't seem to get from Safari 15.

So what methods exist to download private videos from YouTube on macOS without installing a new browser or compiling a Rust application manually?

Comment: How about [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/434686/how-to-get-cookies-txt-for-youtube-from-safari/434687#434687)? Have you forgot you've asked same question before?

Comment: @Skye-AT that question seems to be how to get cookies. This question is how to download youtube video on macOS

Comment: And that would be using youtube-dl with cookies.txt, I would say it's essentially the same question...

Comment: You can easily copy cookies from Safari via the built-in developer tools (which is basically documented on the linked question).